# A algorithm Question related to Linkedlist

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to return middle node from a singly linkedlist here,
and this is how I approach, but I keep getting Nullpointexception here.
Can anybody explain where I am getting wrong?

```
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode(int x) { val = x; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode middleNode(ListNode head) {
    ListNode slow = head; 
    ListNode fast = head;
        if (slow == null) {
            return null;
        }
        if (slow.next.next == null) {
            return slow.next;
        }
        while (slow.next != null && fast.next.next != null) {
            slow = slow.next;
            fast = fast.next.next;
        }
        return slow;
    }
}
```

Comment: On which line you get it?

Comment: Thank for you for the reply first of all,For example, if the input is an array of ListNode like [1,2,3,4,5], then I expect it to return node of 3, but it returns NullpointsException.. This is where I get stuck

Comment: Seems unlikely that the problem is in the code you posted. Are you *sure* the error is occurring in your `middleNode` method? You should start up your debugger and single-step the code.

Comment: My bad, I accidentally copied the answer code instead of my code that i have a question on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that there is no error in this code.

I just ran your code with a Linked List that looks like `1->2->3->4->5`, like you stated in the comments, and it works just fine.

Also, this is a question from [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/middle-of-the-linked-list/), and the code you posted passes all of the test cases on there. In fact, this code looks identical to the third solution that is provided on there (which you can see by clicking the "solution" tab).

---

**Post-Edit:**

The reason why you're getting a null pointer exception in your updated code is because you're not checking whether or not `fast.next` is null prior to accessing `fast.next.next`. Thus, if you change the while-loop condition from `while (slow.next != null && fast.next.next != null)` to `while (slow.next != null && fast.next != null && fast.next.next != null)`, then you'll get rid of the null pointer exception.

However, this will still result in a verdict of Wrong Answer, because your algorithm is not correct.

You should not be checking whether `fast.next` and `fast.next.next` are non-null but instead, you should be checking whether `fast` and `fast.next` are null. I suggest you work it out on paper to see why (the code you posted will fail for `1->2->3->4->5->6`, for which the answer should be ListNode `3`). The updated code with these changes is provided below:

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode middleNode(ListNode head) {
    ListNode slow = head; 
    ListNode fast = head;
        if (slow == null) {
            return null;
        }

        if (slow.next == null) {
            return slow;
        }

        while (slow.next != null && fast != null && fast.next != null) {
            slow = slow.next;
            fast = fast.next.next;
        }
        return slow;
    }
}
```

Comment: My fault, I accidentally copied the other code, and the code I was going to post is this

Comment: No problem. Check my edit. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I truly appreciate of the answer! Thank you Ekesh !